# How can I get the selected cell from a NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can I get the selected cell from a NSOutlineView?
Not the item, but the cell.
Not the datacell but the current cell itself.

It's a cell based NSOutlineView.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the delegate. `willDisplayCell:` is called when a cell changes its selection state.

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    id selectedItem = [outlineView itemAtRow:outlineView.selectedRow];
    if (item == selectedItem) {
        // 'cell' is selected cell for 'tableColumn'
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the methods from the "Handling Selection" section of `NSOutlineViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
func getSelectedCell() -> NSTableCellView? {
    if let view = outlineView.rowView(atRow: outlineView.selectedRow, makeIfNecessary: false) {
        return view.view(atColumn: outlineView.selectedColumn) as? NSTableCellView
    }
    return nil
}
```

see also [NSOutlineView, how to get the selected cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074337/nsoutlineview-how-to-get-the-selected-cell)