# NSOutlineView, how to get the selected cell

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want to get the selected cell from the NSOutlineView control. I found a solution here: [How can I get the selected cell from a NSOutlineView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164434/how-can-i-get-the-selected-cell-from-a-nsoutlineview). It says

> Use the delegate. willDisplayCell: is called when a cell changes its selection state.

However when I test it, I found that my `willDisplayCell:` is not be called.

Here's my code, it can be run normally, but the `willDisplayCell:` method has never been called. Where did I make a mistake? Thanks.

```
class TreeNode: NSObject{
    var name: String = ""
    private(set) var isLeaf: Bool = false
    var children: [TreeNode]?

    init(name: String, isLeaf: Bool){
        self.name = name
        self.isLeaf = isLeaf
        if !isLeaf{
            children = [TreeNode]()
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sourceList: NSOutlineView!

    private var data = TreeNode(name: "Root", isLeaf: false)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        for i in 0..<10{
            let node = TreeNode(name: "name \(i)", isLeaf: i % 2 == 0)
            data.children?.append(node)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDataSource {
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        if let item = item as? TreeNode, !item.isLeaf {
            return item.children!.count
        }
        return 1
    }
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        return !((item as? TreeNode)?.isLeaf ?? false)
    }
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        if let item = item as? TreeNode {
            if item.isLeaf{
                return item
            }else{
                return item.children![index]
            }
        }
        return data
    }
}
extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, willDisplayCell cell: Any, for tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) {
        print("called")
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        let cell: NSTableCellView?
        if let item = item as? TreeNode{
            cell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue:  "DataCell"), owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
            cell?.textField?.stringValue = item.name
        }else{
            cell = nil
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `willDisplayCell:` and the other cell methods are called by cell based outline views. The answer to the linked question isn't a good idea. Do you want to get the selection or do you want a trigger when the selection changes?

Comment: @Willeke thank you your reply. To be more exact, I want to get the NSTextField control in the selected tree node that displays the node's name. I know `outlineViewSelectionDidChange:` method, but I can't use it to get the NSTextField control.

Comment: `willDisplayCell` is the wrong place anywhere. Get the information from the model (the data source) or use Cocoa Bindings.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem myself. The following code is how to get the selected cell:

```
func getSelectedCell() -> NSTableCellView? {
    if let view = self.sourceList.rowView(atRow: self.sourceList.selectedRow, makeIfNecessary: false) {
        return view.view(atColumn: self.sourceList.selectedColumn) as? NSTableCellView
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now I can access the `NSTextField` control by the code `getSelectedCell()?.textField`.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `view(atColumn:row:makeIfNecessary:)`? You can't have a selected row and a selected column.

Comment: @Willeke, thanks for ur reply. But why I can't have a selected row and column? This code works fine for my project and I use it to get the right cell, right textfield. Everything seems to be all right.

Comment: Is `selectedColumn` >= 0? I'm surprised it works (and it does work, I tried, `view(atColumn:)` checks if the column < 0 and sets it to 0).

Comment: @Willeke, yes, you're right, the `selectedColumn` is always `-1`. But it still works. At first, I use `0` for the `atColumn` parameter, since I have only one table column, it works. Later, I found the `selectedColumn` property, so I use it, and it still works. I don't know why, but really it works fine. I test on Xcode 9.3, swift4.